# Multi-variable scatterplot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I have a data set with 12 categorical variables (I'm trying to graph measurements by month) and varying numbers of observations for each variable. A simple scatterplot isn't working and I can't figure out any other code that will let me plot my data.

```
Data: 
     June   July    Aug   Sept    Oct Nov    Dec    Jan    Feb  March  April    May
1  0.2315 0.8933 0.5255 0.7978 0.7581  NA 0.6729 0.7831 0.3599 0.3233 0.4901 0.2591
2  0.3030 1.0136 0.3487 1.0823 0.7639  NA 0.9925 0.7843 0.3438 0.3374 0.5919 0.2978
3  0.3850 0.5880 0.7762 0.5351 0.4139  NA 0.2131 0.7609 0.5401 0.5158 0.4427     NA
4  0.2278 0.5880 0.2531 0.6209 1.0323  NA 0.3389 0.7743 0.6315 0.5639 0.0677     NA
5  0.2374 0.7155 0.2701 0.5842 0.2598  NA     NA 0.9977 1.0104     NA 0.3364     NA
6  0.2390 0.7418 0.2974 0.7259 0.2544  NA     NA 0.6019 0.4063     NA 0.5175     NA
7  0.3298 0.4235     NA 0.8536 0.3954  NA     NA 0.7475 0.4842     NA 0.5094     NA
8  0.3861 0.3711     NA 0.8663 0.2405  NA     NA 0.7484     NA     NA 0.6044     NA
9  0.2012 0.5342     NA 1.1538 1.3359  NA     NA 0.3515     NA     NA 0.5918     NA
10 0.2791 0.4916     NA 0.7292 1.6786  NA     NA 0.3555     NA     NA     NA     NA
11     NA 0.4715     NA 0.2570 0.6435  NA     NA 0.5495     NA     NA     NA     NA
12     NA 0.2511     NA 0.1893 0.3038  NA     NA 0.3295     NA     NA     NA     NA
13     NA 0.2627     NA 0.7264 0.2344  NA     NA 0.6638     NA     NA     NA     NA
14     NA 0.2993     NA 0.9806 0.8943  NA     NA 0.7682     NA     NA     NA     NA
15     NA 0.3847     NA 0.2676     NA  NA     NA 1.4591     NA     NA     NA     NA
16     NA 0.3048     NA 1.6670     NA  NA     NA 0.5868     NA     NA     NA     NA
17     NA 0.3961     NA 1.8325     NA  NA     NA 0.8361     NA     NA     NA     NA
18     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  NA     NA 0.8399     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Where is your code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data is called `df`

```
library(reshape2); library(ggplot2)
df <- melt(df, NULL)
ggplot(df, aes(x = rep(1:18,12), y = value, group = variable)) + geom_line(aes(col = variable))
```

[image]